# Looking to clean up my equations

Tags: equations

I want to improve the appearance of my equation section. The long regression equations currently are tall/stacked and I think they might looked better if they were stretched out a little horizontally. Additionally, my third equation technically isn't an equation but a sentence (you'll know what I mean when you see it). Could you please have a look?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}


\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}
\section{Empirical Results}

OLS Regression is used to estimate the following equations:

\ \ 
\\

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:first}
\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{CEO Salary} \\
=&\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}+
\beta_2\,\text{bonus}\\ 
& +\beta_3\,\text{stock awards}\\ 
& +\beta_4\,\text{option awards} \\
& +\beta_5\,\text{other compensation}\beta_6\,\text{age} \\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq} 
+\beta_8\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry} 
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:second}
\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{Total Compensation}\\
=&
\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}\\ 
& +\beta_2\,\text{age} 
+\beta_3\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_4\,\text{interaction term?}\\
& +\beta_5\,\text{industry} 
\beta_6\,\text{volume}\\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq}
+\beta_8\,\text{male}\\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry}
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume}
\end{array}
\end{equation} 

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:third}
\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{Same as model (1) without industry dummies}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

And here's how it currently looks:

[image]

Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly you should never end a paragraph with `\\` and never have a blank line before a displayed equation

```
\ \ 
\\
```

before the equation produces output of maximum badness

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 45--47
```

The main visual thing that seems wrong with the equations is that you have the first line to the right of the =, but also don't use `array` for equations (it is designed for arrays/matrices and sets cells in textstyle not display style and has the wrong spacing) use the ams alignments instead

You shouldn't really have consecutive display math (I have consecutive multline here) but it's getting late and perhaps this will get you closer, I just compensated with a negative vskip here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}


\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}
\section{Empirical Results}

OLS Regression is used to estimate the following equations:
\begin{multline}
\label{eqn:first}
\text{CEO Salary}={}\\
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}+
\beta_2\,\text{bonus}\\ 
& +\beta_3\,\text{stock awards}\\ 
& +\beta_4\,\text{option awards} \\
& +\beta_5\,\text{other compensation}\beta_6\,\text{age} \\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq} 
+\beta_8\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry} 
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume} 
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{multline}
\label{eqn:second}
\text{Total Compensation}={}\\
\begin{aligned}[t]
&
\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}\\ 
& +\beta_2\,\text{age} 
+\beta_3\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_4\,\text{interaction term?}\\
& +\beta_5\,\text{industry} 
\beta_6\,\text{volume}\\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq}
+\beta_8\,\text{male}\\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry}
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume}
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:third}
\text{Same as model \eqref{eqn:first} without industry dummies}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the `mathtools` package provides the "subsidiary" environment `multlined` which can be used  just like `multline` except that multiple instances can be nested inside `gather`.